# Why does the following zsh command change my output?

Tags: zsh, syntax, echo

When I execute this command

```
port=3128
echo $port:localhost
```

I get `3128ocalhost` as output.

**PS**:
*When I change the first 'l' char it works fine.
I can't even google it.*

Comment: Executing how? Where? Is this in a script you wrote on Windows?

Comment: Not when i do it ;) You are copying this from somewhere else? a website?

Comment: I got this script from a public repository, so my mates don't have this problem... but I have.
And I execute this script on Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

In Zsh, [`:l` is as a modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers), making the expansion lowercase. Since the port is a number, you didn't get that extra hint, but if we put some uppercase characters the difference is visible.

```
% port=AS10X
% echo $port:localost
as10xocalost
```

To keep the `:l` literal in Zsh, escape it: `$port\:localost`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I have one more moment I'd like to understand - this code from a public repository - so, why my mates don't have this problem but I have?
We are using the same os - it's OS X and also we have same environment.

Comment: @ThomasJJ You are welcome. The first things I'd like you to do is to confirm that you were running Zsh (verify it with `echo $0`, and add the output to your question by editing it). Somehow you have installed Zsh and your mates have not, they are likely running Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet of code, it's works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

PORT=3128
echo "$PORT:localhost"
```

> #output : 3128:localhost

Answer (score 0):

In bash your code works.

Try to specify the SHELL like...

(in a script)

```
#!/bin/bash
port=3128
echo $port:localhost
```

(in a terminal)

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
port=3128
echo $port:localhost
```